# How are 802.11 neighbors communicated to APs?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

The 802.11k specifies that an STA can send a "Neighbor Report Request". I understand how the STA sends and gets that from the AP, but how does the AP get this information from other APs?

Also, how does an AP know which is an authenticated neighbor on the same WAN and who is not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

802.11k applies to controller-based wireless networks, where all APs are controlled by a central controller.  That controller has a complete view of the wireless infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Can you elaborate on how the controller communicates to the AP the neighbors the AP has? I've been looking through specs and code. So far, I haven't come across anything detailing this yet.

Comment: That's mostly proprietary to the manufacturer.  Cisco, for example, use encrypted tunnels between the controller and AP for management traffic.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if that would be the case. Much obliged!